# Chart and graph component for website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jsp, graph

I am working on a website where I need to display lot of charts/graphs (dynamic pie,line,bar charts etc)

I am open to

- Technology - ASP.NET or JSP
- Database - MSSQL
- Front-end - HTML/CSS/AJAX/JQuery

I know that there are components like **Google Charts API** to do this. I want to know whether there are any other good graph components out there which I could look into.

Comment: So you want us to do your research for you?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too subject to opinion, rather than factual answers, and is thus not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I just wanted any suggestions if you have. Sorry if this doesn't count as a question!

Comment: This question can never have a single answer which is acceptable by *everyone*. This kind of questions doesn't belong here in a Q&A site, but more in a discussion forum. Find one and post over there instead.

Comment: There's this awesome website called Google, take a look there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High charts has a great arsenal of charting tools for JavaScript:  http://www.highcharts.com .

To get server related data you can use Ajax.  Here's jQuery's way to use Ajax to pull server data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/